# implementing the browser navigation in react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In browser , we do have back and forward button to navigate back and forth. If we are in the first page back will be disabled and in the last page forward is disabled. Am trying to implement the same in react application using react router.I can navigate to different pages on click of navigation menu But i need a help on implementing the browser navigation in the react application.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Redirect, Switch, Route, withRouter } from "react-router";

import Page1 from "./Page1";
import Page2 from "./Page2";
import Page3 from "./Page3";

const App = (props) => {
return (
<React.Fragment>
  <button>prev</button>
  <button>next</button>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/page1" />} />
    <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
    <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
    <Route path="/page3" component={Page3} />
  </Switch>
  </React.Fragment>
);
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

can u help me in implementing the browser navigation here?

Answer (score 0):

The Solution to your problem, you can control using useHistory provided by react-router.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Redirect, Switch, Route, withRouter, useHistory } from "react-router";

import Page1 from "./Page1";
import Page2 from "./Page2";
import Page3 from "./Page3";

const App = (props) => {
    const history = useHistory();

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>Prev</button>
            <button onClick={() => history.goForward()}>Next</button>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/page1" />} />
                <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
                <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
                <Route path="/page3" component={Page3} />
            </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: I need to disable the back button when user is in the first page and nice Verse for the forward button too

Comment: Go through this doc!, you can't access the entire history of your browser, blocked for security purposes! [See this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history)